# How do I implement a BFS tree algorithm using a linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list, breadth-first-search

I am trying to output a BFS tree using a linked list. However, I am having trouble implementing the algorithm. I am getting stuck on how to implement the linked list graph into the algorithm. I am not too sure how I can create a matrix of false and true array then iterating through it to find the false nodes according to the child node that is chosen. The output I should be receiving is

```
0: 1 3
1: 2 4
3:
4:
```

Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.vertex = value
        self.next = None


class AdjGraph:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.graph = [None] * self.data

    # Add edges
    def addEdge(self, vertice, edge):
        currNode = self.graph[vertice]
        newNode = Node(edge)
    
        if currNode == None:
            self.graph[vertice] = newNode 
            return
    
        while currNode != None:
            if currNode.next == None:
                currNode.next = newNode
                break
            currNode = currNode.next

    # Implement BFS Graph
    def bfs(self, s):
        # Set discovered[s] = true, discovered[v] = false for all other v
        discovered = [False] * self.graph
        discovered[s] = True
        # Intialize L[0] to consist of the single element s
        layer = []
        layer.append(s)
        # Set the counter i = 0
        i = 0
        # Set the current BFS tree T = None
        T = None

        # While L[i] is not empty
        while layer:
            # Initialize an empty list L[i+1]
            empty_list = layer[i+1]
            print (s, end = " ")
            # For each node u is an element of L[i]
            for u in layer[i]:
                # Consider each edge (u, v) incident to u
                if discovered[v] == False:
                    # Set discovered[v] = true
                    discovered[v] = True
                    # Add edge (u, v) to the tree T
                    T.append
                    # Add v to the list L[i+1]
                    empty_list.append(v)

    # Print the graph
    def printGraph(self):
        adj_list = "Adjacency List"
        for i in range(self.data):
            adj_list += "\n\nNode " + str(i) + ": "
            temp = self.graph[i]
            while temp:
                adj_list += str(temp.vertex) + " "
                temp = temp.next
        print(adj_list)


g = AdjGraph(5)
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 3)
g.addEdge(1, 0)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 3)
g.addEdge(1, 4)
g.addEdge(2, 1)
g.addEdge(2, 4)
g.addEdge(3, 0)
g.addEdge(3, 1)
g.addEdge(3, 4)
g.addEdge(4, 1)
g.addEdge(4, 2)
g.addEdge(4, 3)
g.bfs(0)
```

Comment: Can you fix the indentation? You have unindented functions which are maybe intended as methods?

Comment: What is the purpose of the linked lists? I don't see it.

Comment: Sorry about that I am new do programming and this website. The purpose of the linked list is to create an adjacency list. The linked list adding an edge to each node. Then creating a BFS tree from the adjacency list.

Comment: What is `v`? It is nowhere defined?

Comment: Is there any requirement in the *order* that the BFS algorithm visits the nodes? I mean, is the order in which edges are added with `addEdge` important with regard to the result?

Comment: Is the expected output *text*, or a *dictionary*, or...?

Comment: The expected output should be a text and there is no requirement in the order.

Comment: OK, so if the order can be different, the output can be totally different, right? It could be `0: 3 1` and then `1: 2` and then `2:` and then `3: 4` and finally `4:`.

Comment: It should return all the connected nodes from the chosen node. For example, g.bfs(0) should return 0: 1 3, 1: 2 4, 2: , 3: , 4:

Comment: I don't think you understand what I mean. If during BFS nodes can be visited in a different order, then the BFS tree will extend differently, and you'll get different edges in that spanning tree, leading to different output. See the output I mentioned, which is what you get when node 3 is expanded before node 1.

Comment: BTW, your code has many, many errors. Your BFS mentions `T.append`, but does not call it. It never uses the `vertex` attribute of the node, it never changes the value of `i`, ...etc, ...etc. You should really debug your code to eliminate the most basic problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `bfs` code has many issues. I will not list them all, but:

- `[False] * self.graph` does not make sense as `self.graph` is not a number
- `layer[i+1]` does not exist when it is first evaluated
- `for u in layer[i]` does not work as `layer[i]` is a node number (`s`), and is not iterable
- `empty_list` receives values, but they are never used.
- `T.append` does nothing.
- Although there is an attempt to put data in `T`, it is never used.
- The value of `i` is never changed.
- `bfs` only modifies local variables and doesn't return anything. So after it has been called, there is nothing different from before it was called, except for the node numbers that are printed. But I suppose that was only there for debugging purposes, as it does not follow the output format.

As I mentioned in comments, as the expected output corresponds to the search tree that is formed by a breadth-first search (BFS), the output could be different depending on the order of adding nodes and the order of visiting nodes.

The example graph looks like this:

```
        0-----1
         \   /|\
          \ / | \
           3--4--2
```

A BFS that starts in node 0 could produce either of these search trees:

```
0-----1          0-----1
 \    |\          \     \
  \   | \          \     \
   3  4  2          3--4  2
```

This depends on the order in which nodes 1 and 3 are expanded. The first tree is the result when node 1 is expanded first, while the second tree is the result when node 3 is expanded first.

Now, since you want to work with linked lists, I should also mention that *adding* a node to a linked list is more efficiently done at the *start* of the list than at the end (unless you also maintain a *tail* reference). So I would suggest not to have the `currNode` loop, but to *prepend* the new node at the start of the list. This way there is no loop. This of course impacts the order of the nodes that end up in the list.

The following code will remove edges from the graph that are not used in the BFS tree. That way you can use your `printGraph` function to output the result.

Code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, nxt=None):
        self.vertex = value
        self.next = nxt


class AdjGraph:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size
        self.graph = [None] * self.size

    def addEdge(self, vertex, edge):
        # Prepend the new node to the linked list
        self.graph[vertex] = Node(edge, self.graph[vertex]) 

    def bfs(self, s):
        discovered = [False] * self.size
        discovered[s] = True
        layer = [s]

        while layer:
            empty_list = []
            for u in layer:
                keep = None # this will be the new (filtered) list for self.graph[u]
                v = self.graph[u]
                while v:
                    nxt = v.next
                    if not discovered[v.vertex]:
                        discovered[v.vertex] = True
                        empty_list.append(v.vertex)
                        # Prepend v to the keep linked list
                        v.next = keep
                        keep = v
                    v = nxt
                self.graph[u] = keep
            layer = empty_list  # start working with the next layer

    def printGraph(self):
        adj_list = "Adjacency List"
        for i in range(self.size):
            adj_list += "\nNode " + str(i) + ": "
            temp = self.graph[i]
            while temp:
                adj_list += str(temp.vertex) + " "
                temp = temp.next
        print(adj_list)


g = AdjGraph(5)
g.addEdge(0, 1)
g.addEdge(0, 3)
g.addEdge(1, 0)
g.addEdge(1, 2)
g.addEdge(1, 3)
g.addEdge(1, 4)
g.addEdge(2, 1)
g.addEdge(2, 4)
g.addEdge(3, 0)
g.addEdge(3, 1)
g.addEdge(3, 4)
g.addEdge(4, 1)
g.addEdge(4, 2)
g.addEdge(4, 3)
g.bfs(0)
g.printGraph()
```

Output:

```
Adjacency List
Node 0: 1 3 
Node 1: 2 
Node 2: 
Node 3: 4 
Node 4:
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the information. I have learned a lot and see all my mistakes.